# python multithreading cannot output a complete result

Tags: python, multithreading

I use multithreading to insert data to database, but it cannot return correct result, the code is in belows:

```
class MongoInsertThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,  queue, thread_id):
        super(MongoInsertThread, self).__init__()
        self.thread_id = thread_id
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        print(self.thread_id,': ', self.queue.get())

def save_to_mongo_with_thread():
    q = queue.Queue()

    for e in range(3):
        for i in range(10):
            q.put([i], block=False)
        threads = []
        for i in range(5): ##(1)
            threads.append(MongoInsertThread(q, i))
        for t in threads:
            t.start()
        for t in threads:
            t.join()
        print("+++++++++++++++++++++++")
```

but the result generated by the code is:

```
0 :  [0]
1 :  [1]
2 :  [2]
3 :  [3]
4 :  [4]
+++++++++++++++++++++++
0 :  [5]
1 :  [6]
2 :  [7]
3 :  [8]
4 :  [9]
+++++++++++++++++++++++
0 :  [0]
1 :  [1]
2 :  [2]
3 :  [3]
4 :  [4]
+++++++++++++++++++++++
```

which is not I wanted, and I hope the result is:

```
0 :  [0]
1 :  [1]
2 :  [2]
3 :  [3]
4 :  [4]
0 :  [5]
1 :  [6]
2 :  [7]
3 :  [8]
4 :  [9]
+++++++++++++++++++++++
0 :  [0]
1 :  [1]
2 :  [2]
3 :  [3]
4 :  [4]
0 :  [5]
1 :  [6]
2 :  [7]
3 :  [8]
4 :  [9]
+++++++++++++++++++++++
0 :  [0]
1 :  [1]
2 :  [2]
3 :  [3]
4 :  [4]
0 :  [5]
1 :  [6]
2 :  [7]
3 :  [8]
4 :  [9]
+++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Maybe in the `for` loop went some wrong, but I cannot find any solutions to deal with it. where is wrong with my code? And how can I deal with it?
And I use `11` to substitute `5` in `##(1)`, and it suspended, how can I deal with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using thread-pool? Here is my approach:

- Change your `MongoInsertThread.run()` method to make it run `forever` until it sees some `return` point (a `None` job, e.g.).
- Make a thread-pool `MongoInsertThread` threads.
- Update `save_to_mongo_with_threads`: start the thread-pool -> put jobs to queue -> stop the thread-pool.

**Updated**: Explain a bit more about thread-pool in this solution

- Thread-pool is a collection of multiple threads.
- Threads within a thread-pool share the same queue of jobs.
- Each thread runs forever (`MongoInsertThread.run()` method):

  - (1) gets a job from the shared queue.
  - (2) if the job is `None` -> break the `forever` loop (i.e. stop current thread)
  - (3) else (the job is not `None`) -> processes the job.
  - (4) go to (1).

Code:

```
import threading
import queue
import time


class MongoInsertThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue, thread_id):
        super(MongoInsertThread, self).__init__()
        self.thread_id = thread_id
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            job = self.queue.get()
            if job is None:
                return
            print(self.thread_id, ": ", job)


class ThreadPool:
    def __init__(self, queue, thread_count):
        self._queue = queue
        self._thread_count = thread_count
        self._workers = []
        for thread_id in range(thread_count):
            worker_thrd = MongoInsertThread(queue, thread_id)
            self._workers.append(worker_thrd)

    def start(self):
        for worker_thrd in self._workers:
            worker_thrd.start()

    def stop(self):
        # put None job, each worker thread picks one then stops
        for worker_thrd in self._workers:
            self._queue.put(None)
        # wait for worker threads
        for worker_thrd in self._workers:
            worker_thrd.join()


def save_to_mongo_with_threads():
    q = queue.Queue()

    pool = ThreadPool(q, 5)
    pool.start()

    time.sleep(1.0)

    for e in range(3):
        for i in range(10):
            q.put([e, i])
        print("+++++++++++++++++++++++")

    time.sleep(1.0)

    pool.stop()


save_to_mongo_with_threads()
```

**Note**: Jobs might be not evenly distributed among threads. One possible output:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++
0 :  [0, 0]
2 :  [0, 1]
4 :  [0, 3]
1 :  [0, 4]
0 :  [0, 5]
2 :  [0, 6]
4 :  [0, 7]
3 :  [0, 2]
+++++++++++++++++++++++
2 :  [0, 9]
0 :  [0, 8]
+++++++++++++++++++++++
2 :  [1, 2]
0 :  [1, 3]
4 :  [1, 0]
4 :  [1, 7]
1 :  [1, 4]
2 :  [1, 5]
4 :  [1, 8]
1 :  [1, 9]
2 :  [2, 0]
4 :  [2, 1]
1 :  [2, 2]
2 :  [2, 3]
4 :  [2, 4]
3 :  [1, 1]
2 :  [2, 6]
4 :  [2, 7]
3 :  [2, 8]
2 :  [2, 9]
1 :  [2, 5]
0 :  [1, 6]
```

Comment: Thank you! But it's a little bit hard to understand.

Comment: when initialize the `ThreadPool`, you pass an empty queue, and then start it,  there is no data sending to the thread, why it doesn't go wrong? @duong_dajgja

Answer (score 1):

The output you are seeing is a result of how you populate the `queue`, consider what the block

```
for i in range(10):
    q.put([i], block=False)
```

is doing; it is queuing `10` new values to `q`, subsequently the block

```
for i in range(5):
    threads.append(MongoInsertThread(q, i))
```

passes queue to `5` threads, each of which calls `get()` once for a total of `5` calls. So at line 16 in the first iteration of `e`, `q` is comprised of

```
[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]
```

After the threads complete it contains

```
[5], [6], [7], [8], [9]
```

After which `10` more values are queued, yielding

```
[5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]
```

`5` values are then again removed leaving

```
[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]
```

After which another `10` values are queued,

```
[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]
```

Followed by the last removal which leaves

```
[5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]
```

If you want `10` elements removed every time you must have `10` calls to `get()`, in the setup you have this requires `10` threads, or changing the thread loop to

```
for i in range(10):
  threads.append(MongoInsertThread(q, i))
```

However this isn't necessarily the most efficient way to do this, since for `100` elements you must generate `100` threads. It is better to generate a smaller number of threads and have them each call `get()` multiple times, like so

```
class MongoInsertThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,  queue, thread_id, m):
        super(MongoInsertThread, self).__init__()
        self.thread_id = thread_id
        self.queue = queue
        self.m = m

    def run(self):
        for i in range(self.m):
            # Using sys,stdout.write keeps the output lines from getting garbled
            sys.stdout.write(str(self.thread_id)+': '+str(self.queue.get())+"\n")

def save_to_mongo_with_thread():
    q = Queue.Queue()
    n1 = 11
    n2 = 5

    for e in range(3):
        for i in range(n1):
            q.put([i], block=False)
        threads = []
        # Caution - if n1 < n2 this will fail
        for i in range(n2-1):
            threads.append(MongoInsertThread(q, i, (n1/n2)))
        threads.append(MongoInsertThread(q, n2-1, (n1/n2)+(n1 % n2))) # Handles (n1 % n2 != 0)
        for t in threads:
            t.start()
        for t in threads:
            t.join()
        print("+++++++++++++++++++++++")
```

Sample output (using `n1 = 11` not `n1 = 10`)

```
0: [0]
0: [1]
1: [2]
1: [3]
2: [4]
2: [5]
3: [6]
3: [7]
4: [8]
4: [9]
4: [10]
+++++++++++++++++++++++
0: [0]
0: [1]
1: [2]
1: [3]
2: [4]
2: [5]
3: [6]
3: [7]
4: [8]
4: [9]
4: [10]
+++++++++++++++++++++++
0: [0]
0: [1]
1: [2]
2: [3]
1: [4]
2: [5]
3: [6]
3: [7]
4: [8]
4: [9]
4: [10]
+++++++++++++++++++++++
```